# Why does my TUN device not send UDP/IP to 192.168.2.x?

Tags: tunnel, udp

I've set up a TUN device on my host computer using this script:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

#do NAT on packets from our 'local' net
iptables -t nat --flush POSTROUTING
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

#initialise the tun device (tun0)
ip tuntap add dev tun0 mode tun

#give the tun device IP 10.0.0.1
ifconfig tun0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

#disable IPv6 on tun device
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.tun0.disable_ipv6=1

#some firewall rules
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

I'm trying to send UDP packages from my host computer over wifi to my laptop. The application connected to the TUN device is a server application that uses a protocol similar to SOCKS5 to take formatted TCP packets, constructs UDP/IP packets and sends them to a specified address with a made up src IP (for some reason).

Sending UDP packages over the TUN with a src address of 10.0.0.2 works fine. I can get it up to 10.0.0.0/8 by changing the netmask, but when I set the src (!) ip of the IP packet I want to send over the TUN device to 192.168.2.112 (the actual IP of my host), the TUN device will pick it up, but it is not received on my laptop. Using python to send a UDP datagram normally works as expected and the correct src IP is read on my laptop. The TUN device sends the constructed packets, when the src IP is in the 10.0.0.0/8 range, but not when it is 192.*.

The iptables are empty on both machines, before using the script. What am I missing?

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter: 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter: 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enp0s31f6/rp_filter: 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/lo/rp_filter: 0
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/rp_filter: 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlp4s0/rp_filter: 1
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wwp0s20f0u3c2/rp_filter:1
```

Comment: Is this script being run on your laptop or a different computer? What software attaches to the other end of the tun device? What are the values of `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter`?

Comment: @grawity I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat, your application produces a packet with some source address, puts it into the tun-interface, your host computer forwards it, masquerades it on `eth0`, and then from eth0 it is somehow mysteriously sent via WLAN to your laptop. This works for 10.0.0.2 as source, but not for 192.168.2.112.

However, in reality, you don't have an `eth0` interface, but the interfaces are `enp0s31f6`, `wlp4s0`, and `wwp0s20f0u3c2`.

Is this correct?

If yes, the likely culprit is that you need to masquerade on the WLAN interface instead of `eth0`, and you need to masquerade for all source addresses, not only for 10.0.0.0/8. The real question is how it worked for 10.0.0.2 in the first place, but that is probably explained by the part of your configuration you didn't tell us.

You likely need to masquerade on WLAN because otherwise you'd have to set routes in the other part of your network.

Tools to debug: `ip route get 1.2.3.4` to check routes, `tcpdump -ni wlp4s0` et.c on all interfaces that may be interesting to see where the packets actually go.

Comment: I've been tinkering with the script. At some point I changed `eth0` to `wlp4so`, but am unsure how much else I changed. I will check what you suggested when I am back home. I'm not sure what part of the configuration I withhold, other than the source code of the involved programs.

Comment: If masquerade was active on wlp4so when it worked, then that should be it. What you probably want is a rule that masquerades everything coming from `tun` going to `wlp4so`, no matter which source address. You may also need to accept the reverse direction for existing connections depending on the default policy. See [here](https://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html) for a clean example.

Comment: It seems that I changed the wrong line at the wrong time and didn't get the right combination. After changing the interface to `wlp4so` and keeping the src IP at `10.0.0.2` it works now. Thanks a lot. I learned a bit about NAT and `iptables` in the process.